# How to apply a groupby rolling function to create multiple columns in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, for-loop

I am setting up a volume profile series over a stock data. I have implemented the market profile code from [this github repo](https://github.com/bfolkens/py-market-profile/blob/master/src/market_profile/init.py) and the link to the [data is here](https://github.com/bfolkens/py-market-profile/blob/master/tests/fixtures/google.csv) and the [example here](https://github.com/bfolkens/py-market-profile/blob/master/examples/example.ipynb). Some Sample of data is here:

```
Timestamp          Close    High    Low     Open    Volume
2017-09-27 06:30:00 927.74  927.74  927.74  927.74  14929
2017-09-27 07:00:00 933.0   935.53  928.47  928.745 136776
2017-09-27 07:30:00 932.365 934.0   930.065 932.98  73146
2017-09-27 08:00:00 932.39  933.14  930.3   932.45  56624
2017-09-27 08:30:00 934.8675 935.62 931.1495 932.15 74960
2017-09-27 09:00:00 934.325 935.96  933.6 935.2308  62358
2017-09-27 09:30:00 935.48  935.7   933.56  934.36  45043
2017-09-27 10:00:00 935.5   935.56  933.71  935.385 32434
2017-09-27 10:30:00 935.96  936.86  935.21  935.5   58203
```

Here the author gets the output by applying the function over a slice of rows the index and apply the main function by applying this code:

```
mp = MarketProfile(df, tick_size=1)
mp_slice = mp[df.index.max() - pd.Timedelta(13, 'H'):df.index.max()]
```

Here the function takes a slice of indexes from whole dataframe and apply its function in that slice and the author get the final results through this code:

```
mp_slice.as_dict()
```

What I want is to make `rolling(w)` of indexes and apply that function to the whole Data frame in pandas of index and make new columns in the data frame from the starting date. i.e `df['poc_price']`, `df['value_area'], df[initail_balane']`.etc. (all that includes in the as_dict() function output).

i tried many codes but although nothing get the final output that i want. My least code is:

```
def make_marketprofile(df, window=50, mode='vol', tick_size=1):
    for i in range (0, df.shape[0] - window - 1):
    try:
        mpt = MarketProfile(df[i:i+window], mode=mode, tick_size=0.5)
        mpt_slice = mpt[df[i:i+window].index.min() : 
                    df[i:i+window].index.max()].as_dict()
    except KeyError:
        print('error: {}'.format(df_1['Date'][i+window]))
#        for key, value in mpt_slice():
    df.iloc[i+window] = mpt_slice #value
    try:
         df.drop(['Date'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    except AttributeError:
         pass
    for column in df:
    df[column][1:] = pd.to_numeric(df[column][1:])
    df = df.iloc[window:]
    df.fillna(method = 'ffill', inplace = True)
return df
```

but it throws value error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

So my Problem has basically 2 parts:

```
1- To make a rolling and resample function to apply the market profile function over the dataframe
2- the function makes the outputs in a python dictionary and i want to make new columns as per the dictionary objects.
```

Comment: i dont think ive quite understood your problem but if you want to apply a function over a data set you check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) out.